# Passing multidimensional string array to new activity in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, multidimensional-array

I want to pass a 2d string array to a new activity. i saw many answers but i didnt get anyone. How can i do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Example.class);
Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
mBundle.putSerializable("list", selected_list);
mIntent.putExtras(mBundle);
```

To get the passed array use

```
String[][] passedString_list = (String[][]) bundle.getSerializable("list");
```

Comment: what is bundle??? Bundle bundle???